# Custom tiles and Launchpad for ui5 App

Tags: sapui5, web-ide

I have build some ui5 apps with WEB IDE, now i want to add them to a   fiori like lauchpad. My question is, is there some kind of open source opensap Launchpad available?
I would like to be able to build one of my own with Tiles and Conainers
how can I display the apps and custom a Theme?

I would like to hear some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is no OpenUI5 launchpad available, basically because this would require a backend to serve the tiles assigned etc.

But you can build your own using [Tile control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Tile.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Tile Container](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.7/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.TileContainer/samples) is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Tanks, I have tried it with the tile control, but the navigation does not work (CrossApplicationNavigation). Maybe only in a Fiori Launchpad?
I have two applications in two separate project folders, also I  want to display  the apps view when  clicked on a tile.
Is there an easy way to make this hapend?

  `var oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
                      target: { semanticObject : "Products", action: "display"}
                     });`